# Different return type in RxJava 2 (updating from RxJava1)

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am migrating our app from RxJava 1.x.x to RxJava 2.x.x. I have a problem with one of my method - it returns different return type. I had this method in version 1.x.x :

```
fun permissionsUsers(groupId: String): Observable<PermissionsUsers?> {
        return DatabaseRead.permissions(groupId)
                .flatMap {
                    Observable.from(it).map {
                        combineLatest(DatabaseRead.user(it.getId()), Observable.just(it.level), ::UserLevel)
                    }.toList()
                }
                .flatMap {
                    Observable.combineLatest(it) {
                        var owner: User? = null
                        val editPermissions = mutableListOf<User>()
                        val readOnlyPermissions = mutableListOf<User>()
                        it.forEach {
                            it as UserLevel
                            when (it.level) {
                                Permission.LEVEL_OWNER -> owner = it.user
                                Permission.LEVEL_WRITE -> editPermissions.add(it.user)
                                Permission.LEVEL_READONLY -> readOnlyPermissions.add(it.user)
                            }
                        }
                        PermissionsUsers(checkNotNull(owner, { "Owner doesn't exist" }), editPermissions.sortedBy(User::name), readOnlyPermissions.sortedBy(User::name))
                    }
                }
    }
```

As you can see the result type is `Observable<PermissionsUsers?>`. In RxJava2, the nullable observables are not allowed. I solved this problem with Optional. I also replaced Observable classes with Flowable cause I need to manage Backpressure strategy.  It means that return type is changed from `Observable<PermissionsUsers?>` to `Flowable<Optional<PermissionUsers>>`.
This is the changed method:

```
fun permissionsUsers(groupId: String): Flowable<Optional<PermissionsUsers>> {
        return DatabaseRead.permissions(groupId)
                .flatMap {
                    Flowable.fromIterable(it.toSome()).map {
                        combineLatest(DatabaseRead.user(it.getId()), Flowable.just(it.level.toOptional()), ::UserLevel)
                    }.toList()
                }
                .map {
                    Flowable.combineLatest(it) {
                        var owner: User? = null
                        val editPermissions = mutableListOf<User>()
                        val readOnlyPermissions = mutableListOf<User>()
                        it.forEach {
                            it as UserLevel
                            when (it.level) {
                                Permission.LEVEL_OWNER -> owner = it.user
                                Permission.LEVEL_WRITE -> editPermissions.add(it.user)
                                Permission.LEVEL_READONLY -> readOnlyPermissions.add(it.user)
                            }
                        }
                        PermissionsUsers(checkNotNull(owner, { "Owner doesn't exist" }), editPermissions.sortedBy(User::name), readOnlyPermissions.sortedBy(User::name)).toOptional()
                    }
                }
    }
```

The problem is that now the required return type is wrapped to extra Single. So it looks like this: `Single<Flowable<Optional<PermissionsUsers>>>`
instead of `Flowable<Optional<PermissionsUsers>>`. Do you have any idea how to remove that Single? I cannot change the return type.

Answer (score 0):

[`toList()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#toList()) (which returns a `Single`) is in the wrong place.

Change it from this:

```
return DatabaseRead.permissions(groupId)
        .flatMap {
            Flowable.fromIterable(it.toSome()).map {
                // Map code
            }
        }
        .toList()
        .map {
            // Map code
        }
```

To this:

```
return DatabaseRead.permissions(groupId)
        .flatMap {
            Flowable.fromIterable(it.toSome()).map {
                // Map code
            }.toList()
        }.map {
            // Map code
        }
```

Comment: I updated the code based on your answer. The problem still persists :/ .

Comment: @PepaHruška It still returns a `Single`? [`Flowable.flatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#flatMap(io.reactivex.functions.Function)) and [`Flowable.map()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#map(io.reactivex.functions.Function)) both return a `Flowable`, so unless `DatabaseRead.permissions()` returns a `Single` instead of a `Flowable`...